# inotify / stat: possible race condition

Tags: linux, stat, inotify

Two processes on Linux in C running as user `root` basically do the following: (initialization is not shown)

A:

```
fd=open("/watch/item", O_CREAT, 0);
close(fd);
```

B:

```
inotify_add_watch(inotify_fd, "/watch", IN_CREATE);
stat("/watch/item");
// then poll and process the inotify event
```

In extreme rare cases, the `stat()` returns -1, but no more inotify events will be caught later.

Assumption is if there is race condition, when the inotify event is already generated (`inotify_add_watch()` has not yet done) but afterwards the `stat()` still returns -1?